# How to display hint for a disabled control?

Tags: delphi

I have a check box which will be enabled/disabled at run time. I just want to show different tool tips if it is enabled/disabled. I was thinking about overriding OnMouseEnter event and handle it there but OnMouseEnter will be called only if the control is enabled. How can i possible achieve that behavior? Any help would be appreciated.

I tried to handle OnMouseMove of the form and do something like this

```
procedure Tdlg.pnlTopMouseMove(Sender: TObject;Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  point: TPoint;
  checkBoxCursorPos: TPoint;
begin
  inherited;
  point.X := X;
  point.Y := Y;
  checkBoxCursorPos := chkBx.ScreenToClient(point);
  if (PtInRect(chkBx.ClientRect, checkBoxCursorPos)) then
  begin
    if(chkBx.Enabled) then
      chkBx.Hint := 'Enabled'
    else
      chkBx.Hint := 'Disabled' ;

    Application.ShowHint := True;
  end;

end;
```

but the condition PtinRect is not satisfied. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: A workaround would be placing a graphic control, e.g. an empty image behind your control with the desired hint.

Comment: checkBoxCursorPos := chkBx.ScreenToClient(point) isn't right.

Comment: @Giel: What should i do to get the actual position?

Comment: The MouseMove event's X/Y parameters are client coordinates. You're treating them as screen coordinates now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a simple solution: place an empty TLabel over the checkbox and set its Hint to the value for the disabled checkbox state. The label has to be AutoSize off and you can enforce position and size by its BoundsRect property set to that of the CheckBox.

When the CheckBox is enabled the Hint of the Checkbox is used, while the Hint of the Label is used when the CheckBox is disabled.

Update: just saw that Bummi mentions a similar idea in his comment.

Comment: How does the hint of label displayed when check box is disabled and how it is hidden when the check box is enabled? Does the label gets less preference?

Comment: In short: yes, a TWinControl has higher preference as a TGraphicControl. Although the underlying mechanism is a little bit more complicated.

Comment: A similar but slightly different approach would be to place the CheckBox inside the panel, keep the CheckBox `Hint` property blank and its `ParentHint` property set to true, then use the panel's `Hint` property instead (which will display regardless of the value of `CheckBox.Enabled`).

Answer (score 2):

The official answer: [you can’t](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/05/2028099.aspx).

The workaround: you could try using the *form's* MouseMove-event (assuming that won’t be disabled, of course), and if the mouse cursor is over the relevant control, display the appropriate hint.

Comment: I have updated my question. i am handling mousemove event. can you elaborate how to determine if it is over the control?

Comment: Updated Link:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070405-00/?p=27363
https://web.archive.org/web/20230608162911/https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070405-00/?p=27363

Answer (score 1):

Here is a unit that can show hints for disabled controls.

I used it like this:

```
TATHintControl.Create(self).HintStyleController := GlobalHintStyleController;
```

GlobalHintStyleController is a DevExpress stylecontroller.
Then the unit

```
unit ATHintControl;

{
The purpose of this component is to show hints for disabled controls (VCL doesn't)
It uses timestamp comparison instead of Timers to save resources 
}
interface

uses
  // VCL
  Classes,
  Controls,
  Forms,
  AppEvnts,
  Messages,
  Windows,

  // DevEx
  cxHint;

type
  TGetHintForControlEvent = function(AControl: TControl): string of object;
  THandleControlEvent = function(AControl: TControl): boolean of object;

  TATHintControl = class(TComponent)
  private
    fHintTimeStamp: TDateTime;
    fHintHideTimeStamp: TDateTime;
    fHintControl: TControl;
    fHintVisible: boolean;
    FHintStyleController: TcxHintStyleController;
    FHintShowDelay: Integer;
    FHintHideDelay: Integer;
    fGetHintForControlEvent: TGetHintForControlEvent;
    fHandleControlEvent: THandleControlEvent;
    fApplicationEvents: TApplicationEvents;
    procedure IdleHandler(Sender: TObject; var Done: Boolean);
    procedure ShortcutHandler(var Msg: TWMKey; var Handled: Boolean);
    procedure SetHintStyleController(const Value: TcxHintStyleController);
    procedure HideHint;
    function GetCursorPos(out APoint: TPoint): Boolean;
    function HandleHint: boolean;
  protected
    function GetHintForControl(AControl: TControl): string; virtual;
    function HandleControl(AControl: TControl): boolean; virtual;
  public
    procedure AfterConstruction; override;
  published
    property HintStyleController: TcxHintStyleController read FHintStyleController write SetHintStyleController;
    property OnGetHintForControl: TGetHintForControlEvent read fGetHintForControlEvent write fGetHintForControlEvent;
    property OnHandleControl: THandleControlEvent read fHandleControlEvent write fHandleControlEvent;
  end;

implementation

uses
  Types,
  SysUtils,
  DateUtils;

const
  cHintShowDelay: Integer = 500; // msec
  cHintHideDelay: Integer = 3 * 1000; // 3 sec

{ TATHintControl }

procedure TATHintControl.AfterConstruction;
begin
  inherited;
  fApplicationEvents := TApplicationEvents.Create(self);
  fApplicationEvents.OnIdle := IdleHandler;
  fApplicationEvents.OnShortCut := ShortcutHandler;
  fHintShowDelay := cHintShowDelay;
  fHintHideDelay := cHintHideDelay;
end;

function TATHintControl.GetCursorPos(out APoint: TPoint): Boolean;
begin
{$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM OFF}
  result := Windows.GetCursorPos(APoint);
{$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM ON}
end;

function TATHintControl.GetHintForControl(AControl: TControl): string;
begin
  if Assigned(OnGetHintForControl) then
    result := OnGetHintForControl(AControl)
  else
    result := AControl.Hint;
end;

procedure TATHintControl.HideHint;
begin
  HintStyleController.HideHint;
  fHintTimeStamp := 0;
  fHintVisible := false;
  fHintHideTimeStamp := 0;
end;

procedure TATHintControl.IdleHandler(Sender: TObject; var Done: Boolean);
begin
  if Assigned(HintStyleController) then
    Done := HandleHint;
end;

procedure TATHintControl.SetHintStyleController(
  const Value: TcxHintStyleController);
begin
  FHintStyleController := Value;
end;

procedure TATHintControl.ShortcutHandler(var Msg: TWMKey; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  fHintControl := nil; // clear the HintControl so that keypress causes it to be shown again w/o having to move the mouse
end;

function TATHintControl.HandleControl(AControl: TControl): boolean;
begin
  if Assigned(OnHandleControl) then
    result := OnHandleControl(AControl)
  else
    result := not AControl.Enabled;
end;

function TATHintControl.HandleHint: boolean;
var
  vNow: TDateTime;
  vScreenPos: TPoint;
  vClientPos: TPoint;
  vControl: TControl;
  vHintString: string;
  vForm: TForm;
  vWinControl: TWinControl;
begin
  result := (fHintTimeStamp = 0);
  vForm := Screen.ActiveForm;
  if not Assigned(vForm) then
    exit;
  if not boolean(GetCursorPos(vScreenPos)) then
    exit;
  vNow := Now;

  vControl := nil;
  vWinControl := vForm as TWinControl;
  while Assigned(vWinControl) do
  try
    vClientPos := vWinControl.ScreenToClient(vScreenPos);  
    vControl := vWinControl.ControlAtPos(vClientPos, true, true, true);
    if not Assigned(vControl) then    
    begin
      vControl := vWinControl;
      break;
    end
    else
    if vControl is TWinControl then
      vWinControl := vControl as TWinControl
    else
      vWinControl := nil;    
  except
    exit; // in some cases ControlAtPos can fail with EOleError: Could not obtain OLE control window handle.
  end;

  if (fHintControl <> vControl) then
  begin
    if fHintVisible then
      HideHint;
    if Assigned(vControl) and HandleControl(vControl) then
    begin
      fHintControl := vControl;
      fHintTimeStamp := vNow; // starts timer for hint to show
    end
    else
    begin
      fHintTimeStamp := 0;
      fHintControl := nil;
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    if fHintVisible and (vNow > fHintHideTimeStamp) then
    begin
      HideHint;
    end
    else   // we check HandleControl again here to make sure we still want to show the hint
    if not fHintVisible and Assigned(vControl) and HandleControl(vControl) and (fHintTimeStamp > 0) and (vNow > IncMillisecond(fHintTimeStamp, fHintShowDelay)) then
    begin
      vHintString := GetHintForControl(vControl);
      if vHintString = '' then
        exit;

      HintStyleController.ShowHint(vScreenPos.X + 0, vScreenPos.Y + 18, '', vHintString);
      fHintTimeStamp := vNow;
      fHintControl := vControl;
      fHintVisible := true;
      // base hide delay + dynamic part based on length of the hint string, 500 msec per 30 characters
      fHintHideTimeStamp := vNow + IncMillisecond(0, fHintHideDelay) + ((Length(vHintString) div 20) * EncodeTime(0,0,0,500));
    end
  end;
  result := (fHintTimeStamp = 0);
end;

end.
```